# How to subtract each member of a tuple to find the smallest difference?

Tags: python

So basically I have this tuple and I'm trying to find the smallest difference. Right now I've organised the tuple from biggest to smallest and what I was trying to do was loop through the tuple but it's saying the index is out of range.

```
def seg(t):
    num_seg = 0
    novo_t = ()
    counter = 0
    t = sorted(t)
    for k in reversed(t):
        novo_t += (k,)
    for i in range(len(novo_t) - 1):
        if novo_t[counter] - novo_t[i + 1] < novo_t[counter + 1] - novo_t[i + 2]:
            num_seg = novo_t[counter] - novo_t[i + 1]
        else:
            num_seg = novo_t[counter + 1] - novo_t[i + 2]
        counter += 1
    return num_seg
```

E.G.

if I put this tuple: `(2223,424,1316,99)`

I want the the return Value to be `325 = (424 - 99)`

Comment: Why do you need the first `for` loop? Just `novo_t = reversed(sorted(t))`

Comment: `novo_t[i+2]` doesn't exist on the last iteration.

Comment: Yes, you're conscientiously subtracting 1 from your `range` end value, but you need to subtract 2.

Comment: `sorted()` has a `reverse=True` option, so you don't need to call `reversed()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing outside the tuple when you access `novo_t[i+2]` on the last iteration of the loop.

You can simply make a list of differences, and then use `min()` to get the smallest.

```
def seg(t):
    sorted_t = sorted(t, reverse=True)
    return min(sorted_t[i] - sorted_t[i+1] for i in range(len(sorted_t)-1))
```

Comment: okay that looks way simple, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you use Python 3.10:

```
from itertools import pairwise

def seg(t):
    return min(b - a for a, b in pairwise(sorted(t)))
```

Or in any case:

```
def seg(t):
    t = sorted(t)
    return min(b - a for a, b in zip(t, t[1:]))
```

Or:

```
from operator import sub

def seg(t):
    t = sorted(t)
    return min(map(sub, t[1:], t))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
def seg(t):
    novo_t = sorted(t)
    if len(t) < 2:
        return None
    min_ = t[1]-t[0]
    for i in range(len(t)-1):
        min_ = min(min_, t[i+1]-t[i])
    return min_
```

Comment: oooooooh, that does seem to do the trick, thank u kindly